# Need Regex to filter .SQL files in sequence

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have one batch file (.bat) which contains text like:

```
osql -S %ServerName% -d %DBName% -U %sql_login% -P %sql_passwd% -n -i sp_RejectAccounts_qsel.sql -o sp_RejectAccounts_qsel.out
osql -S %ServerName% -d %DBName% -U %sql_login% -P %sql_passwd% -n -i sp_RejectAccounts_sel.sql -o sp_RejectAccounts_sel.out
osql -S %ServerName% -d %DBName% -U %sql_login% -P %sql_passwd% -n -i sp_GetCompanyRecordCardRequest_01Aug2012.sql -o sp_GetCompanyRecordCardRequest_01Aug2012.out
osql -S %ServerName% -d %DBName% -U %sql_login% -P %sql_passwd% -n -i SPGetCreditTransactions.sql -o SPGetCreditTransactions.out
```

I need a way to get all the .sql files in, say an array of string.
There has been some changes to the text. The regex should find .sql and then move towards the left till it finds a space.

Comment: Just cut between the first `<` and the first `>`. I'd just use IndexOf and Substring..

Comment: I would rather not rely on it. There maybe other < and > characters. Any help with proper regex ?

Comment: `<` and `>` are not valid in filenames. How do you want to find the filenames? Specify in english, and someone can probably translate to regex.

Comment: Do you need only filenames ot full paths?

Comment: VersionInsertScript_Or.sql,Create_GT_GenerateInvoiceTxnsReportData.sql etc are the SQL files hidden in this text and I want them.

Comment: I've edited my question with an example of how to use Regex to get the filenames, though it doesn't take fullpaths out of there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this. (i'm using List as container for the input).
I don't know if it works, perhaps needs abit of adjustments with the index + and -. Depending on the whitespaces.

```
var a = new List<string>{"sqlplus %1/%2 < %ORACLE_CreateScriptsPath%\VersionInsertScript_Or.sql > %ORACLE_CreateScriptsPath%\VersionInsertScript_Or.out",
"sqlplus %1/%2 <  %ORACLE_CreateScriptsPath%\Create_GT_GenerateInvoiceTxnsReportData.sql > %ORACLE_CreateScriptsPath%\Create_GT_GenerateInvoiceTxnsReportData.out",
"sqlplus %1/%2 <  %ORACLE_CreateScriptsPath%\Create_GT_GenerateInvoiceTxnReportDataRD.sql > %ORACLE_CreateScriptsPath%\Create_GT_GenerateInvoiceTxnReportDataRD.out",
"sqlplus %1/%2 <  %ORACLE_CreateScriptsPath%\Create_GT_GenerateTXNInvestigationReport.sql > %ORACLE_CreateScriptsPath%\Create_GT_GenerateTXNInvestigationReport.out",
"sqlplus %1/%2 <  %ORACLE_CreateScriptsPath%\GenerateInvoiceTxnsReportData.sql > %ORACLE_CreateScriptsPath%\GenerateInvoiceTxnsReportData.out",
"sqlplus %1/%2 <  %ORACLE_CreateScriptsPath%\GenerateInvoiceTxnReportDataRD.sql > %ORACLE_CreateScriptsPath%\GenerateInvoiceTxnReportDataRD.out"};

var strings = new List<string>();

foreach(var input in a)
{
var tmpString = input.Substring(input.IndexOf("<")+3);
tmpString = tmpString.Remove(tmpString.IndexOf(">")-1);
strings.Add(tmpString);
}
//Here you have all the SQL files accessible in the strings collection
```

There is also a possibility to use split to get the filenames. Something like this.

```
var fileNames= input.Split(" ").Where(f => f.Contains(".sql")).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        List<string> sqls = File.ReadAllLines("Utils.txt")
                                .Select(s =>
                                {
                                    string temp = s.Substring(s.IndexOf("<"));
                                    return temp = temp.Substring(1, temp.IndexOf(">") - 1).Trim();
                                })
                                .ToList();
```

So, you can specify any algorythm to extract your filename within `Select`. If you specified some more info on how your filename can appear in the file, it could be possible to give a more special code

**EDIT**

Here is another example with `Regex`:

```
        string regex = @"(?<sql>[\w]{1,}.sql)";
        List<string> sqls = File.ReadAllLines("Utils.txt")
                                .Select(s =>
                                {
                                    Match m = Regex.Match(s, regex);
                                    if (m.Success)
                                        return m.Groups["sql"].Value;
                                    else
                                        return string.Empty;
                                })
                                .ToList();
```

**EDIT**

```
List<string> sqls = File.ReadAllLines("Utils.txt").Select(s => s.Split(' ').FirstOrDefault(f => f.Contains(".sql"))).ToList();
```

**EDIT**

AAAAnd you can change the regex I gave you earlier to

`string regex = @"(?<sql>[\S]{1,}.sql)";`

and get same result as through `Split`

Comment: Hi, I have made the text a bit easier. Please re-read my question.

Comment: @AkshayJ Than you don't actually need Regex...it would be enough to use `Split(" ")` method...Jonas W has already given such a variant

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
        string input = @"osql -S %ServerName% -d %DBName% -U %sql_login% -P %sql_passwd% -n -i sp_RejectAccounts_qsel.sql -o sp_RejectAccounts_qsel.out
                        osql -S %ServerName% -d %DBName% -U %sql_login% -P %sql_passwd% -n -i sp_RejectAccounts_sel.sql -o sp_RejectAccounts_sel.out
                        osql -S %ServerName% -d %DBName% -U %sql_login% -P %sql_passwd% -n -i sp_GetCompanyRecordCardRequest_01Aug2012.sql -o sp_GetCompanyRecordCardRequest_01Aug2012.out
                        osql -S %ServerName% -d %DBName% -U %sql_login% -P %sql_passwd% -n -i SPGetCreditTransactions.sql -o SPGetCreditTransactions.out";

        List<string> names = Regex.Matches(input, @"[^\s]+\.sql")
                .Cast<Match>()
                .Select(o => o.Groups[0].Value)
                .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code that will do this.

```
        var input =
            @" > %ORACLE_CreateScriptsPath%\VersionInsertScript_Or.out
```

sqlplus %1/%2 <  %ORACLE_CreateScriptsPath%\Create_GT_GenerateInvoiceTxnsReportData.sql > %ORACLE_CreateScriptsPath%\Create_GT_GenerateInvoiceTxnsReportData.out
sqlplus %1/%2 <  %ORACLE_CreateScriptsPath%\Create_GT_GenerateInvoiceTxnReportDataRD.sql > %ORACLE_CreateScriptsPath%\Create_GT_GenerateInvoiceTxnReportDataRD.out
sqlplus %1/%2 <  %ORACLE_CreateScriptsPath%\Create_GT_GenerateTXNInvestigationReport.sql > %ORACLE_CreateScriptsPath%\Create_GT_GenerateTXNInvestigationReport.out
sqlplus %1/%2 <  %ORACLE_CreateScriptsPath%\GenerateInvoiceTxnsReportData.sql > %ORACLE_CreateScriptsPath%\GenerateInvoiceTxnsReportData.out
sqlplus %1/%2 <  %ORACLE_CreateScriptsPath%\GenerateInvoiceTxnReportDataRD.sql > %ORACLE_CreateScriptsPath%\GenerateInvoiceTxnReportDataRD.out";

```
        var matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"ORACLE_CreateScriptsPath%\\(.*) >");

        // here is your string array.
        var results = matches.Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Groups[1]);

        // echo results.
        Console.Out.WriteLine(string.Join("\r\n", results));
```